# Is it possible to use SRI for the recurly.js cdn?

Tags: javascript, security, cdn, recurly, subresource-integrity

Can the [recurly.js](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js) be used with SRI `integrity`?

I noticed [this](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js/issues/255) issue, which closed noting that integrity hashes are included on release notes, which [they are](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js/releases). Yet when I tried to test this out on codepen:

```
<script src="https://js.recurly.com/v3/recurly.js" integrity="sha256-3892b173d276d2ec8b087d6abe3bfee2"></script>
```

I receive this error in the javascript console:

> Subresource Integrity: The resource 'https://js.recurly.com/v3/recurly.js' has an integrity attribute, but the resource requires the request to be CORS enabled to check the integrity, and it is not. The resource has been blocked because the integrity cannot be enforced.

Am I missing something or did Recurly not enable CORS on that endpoint?

Comment: The response headers from `curl -i -H "Origin: https://example.com" https://js.recurly.com/v3/recurly.js` include the `access-control-allow-origin` header.

Answer (score 0):

Recurly provides CORS support as of rjs v3.0.9 (https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-309-november-12-2014).

This example is for 3.0.9, but it likely applies on all subsequent releases too.
https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js/tree/v3.1.1#beta-features

recurly.configure({
  publicKey: 'YOUR PUBLIC KEY',
  cors: true
});